# Spring Elasticsearch: Adding fields to working POJO class causes IllegalArgumentException: null is not a Map

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

currently we add a dashboard in our spring application with information from our elastic. We use the documented approach via **RestHighLevelClient.**. The request and mapping does work pretty good. However, when we tried to add a few additional fields we expected to get the corresponding values. Instead,we got the following stacktrace:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a Map.
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$MapValueAccessor.getAsMap(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:941) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$MapValueAccessor.get(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:911) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter$ElasticsearchPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:956) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.readProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:266) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.readEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:197) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:177) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.read(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:77) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractElasticsearchTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java:714) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractElasticsearchTemplate$ReadSearchDocumentResponseCallback.doWith(AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java:738) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractElasticsearchTemplate$ReadSearchDocumentResponseCallback.doWith(AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java:724) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.search(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:276) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchPartQuery.execute(ElasticsearchPartQuery.java:120) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.1.jar!/:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar!/:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.findByFooInfo(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.foo.bar.casper.web.InitialConfigurationDashboardController.getInitialConfigurationDashboardPage(InitialConfigurationDashboardController.java:69) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-191]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar!/:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

The new fields look as follows:

```java
package org.foo.bar.casper.datascraping;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Document(indexName = "foo-data")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ElasticInitialConfiguration {

    @Id
    @Field(name = "_id")
    private String id;
    @Field(name = "_meta.isConfigurable.result")
    private String configurable;
    @Field(name = "_meta.isConfigurable.error.message")
    private String errorMessage;

    @Field(name = "_meta.configurationContext.fooInfo")
    private String fooInfo;

    ...
}
```

```java
package org.foo.bar.casper.datascraping;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

public interface DataScrapingRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ElasticInitialConfiguration, String> {


    Page<ElasticInitialConfiguration> findByFooInfo(String fooInfo, Pageable pageable);

}
```

```java
package org.foo.bar.casper.datascraping;

import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.RestClients;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

@Configuration
@NoArgsConstructor
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "org.foo.bar.casper.datascraping")
public class DatascrapingConfiguration {

    @Value("${elastic.username}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${elastic.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${elastic.url}")
    private String url;

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo(url)
                .usingSsl()
                .withBasicAuth(user, password)
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

The new fields are the ones above info, which was always working. The newly added field values are **sometimes null**, which leads in our opinion to the exception.

We tried already some fixes, like adding **@Nullable** to the fields. Another was adding **    @Mapping(mappingPath = "elastic/null_mapping.json")
** with the following json under resources/elastic:

```json
{
  "type": "string",
  "index": "analyzed",
  "analyzer": "word_analyzer",
  "fields": {
    "raw": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "null_value": "NULL"
    }
  }
}
```

We do not know if the json is correct though.

The error seems to be pretty uncommon. We neither found it in the web nor were we able to get at least a different one. So any suggestions are welcome here. It is not an option not to get the fields.

Thank you for your time

Comment: The problem comes from the names of the properties in Elasticsearch containing a dot (`.`). How is the mapping defied in Elasticsearch for these properties? The dot notation implies that the data is a nested object structure.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch, thank you for your thoughts. Sounds like the issue. We are pretty new to elasticsearch. Could you please point us in the direction on how to do it?

Comment: @Hoall Any luck with this? We are facing the same issue with fields containing dots.

Comment: @roadkill the simple solution was just do introduce a class hierachy representing the dot structure. Instead of accessing foo.bar.baz in the document we had a class (POJOs) foo containg bar having field baz.

The main \@Doucment than contains the next level of classes as fields and so on. Hope it helps